# Adjacency matrix from three-dimensional real world coordinates possible or nearest neighbour necessary?

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

**Problem Statement**

I have three dimensional coordinates for a point cloud and I would like to create an adjacency matrix in order to use:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12850-dijkstra-s-shortest-path-algorithm

**Problem Definition**

My coordinates are stored in `BM(40000x3) (columns:1=x, 2=y, 3=z)`.
I have seen questions in this forum creating adjacency matrices for two-dimensional coordinates, but is it also possible for three-dimensions ? and yes could you help me to set-up an algorithm?

Or is it necessary to use nearest neighbours `knnsearch` to find the adjacency? My points are equally spaced (x=5,y=1,z=5).